# How do I set a forms.CharField text programmatically?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Basically I'm trying to create some sort of dynamic form and I'm trying to change the value of a CharField via a post request. Simply, I have the following field in my form:

```
choice = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In the **init** of the form I have something like this:

```
for key, value in request.post.items():
    if key == 'choice' and value != '':
        self.fields['choice'] = value
```

That obviously does not work because I'm assigning a string (value) to a CharField (choice). Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just pass `request.post` in the constructor?

Comment: I'm actually trying to create the form dynamically. So I'm creating other 'choice's CharFields in the constructor (based on the post arguments) and trying to fill them with the post values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something along the lines of http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/?

in the example it adds X number of char fields via the init

```
for i, question in enumerate(extra):
            self.fields['custom_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label=question)
```

Should be able to extend extra for different form fields.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but the link helped me a lot to get it right, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by the 'value' of the field.

If you're trying to change what is shown when the form is displayed initially, you need to pass an `initial` dictionary with a key corresponding to the field name:

```
self.initial['choice'] = 'myvalue'
```

If you're trying to change what gets passed into validation and then to `cleaned_data`, you need to change the `data` parameter:

```
self.data['choice'] = 'myvalue'
```

Comment: You can't ever edit self.data because it is a QueryDict and it is immutable.